# SQL server database Role management - Azure SQL MI

Tags: sql-server, permissions, users, role, azure-sql-managed-instance

In my database I have multiple users with SQL server authentication login and AD login.

For ex: User 1 and user 2 are from same team(ABC), if I create a role db_abc

User 1 needs read access to table a and table b.
User 2 needs read access to table a, b and additionally to table c.

How do I manage this case? Should permissions be given at user level than to roles.? 
What is the best practice in managing users and roles?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is the best practice in managing users and roles?

Create custom roles and grant permissions to the roles; then add users to the roles.

eg:

```
create role reader_abc
grant select on dbo.a to reader_abc
grant select on dbo.b to reader_abc
grant select on dbo.c to reader_abc

create role reader_ab
grant select on dbo.a to reader_abc
grant select on dbo.b to reader_abc

alter role reader_abc add member alice
alter role reader_ab add member joe
```

You can also assign permissions to an entire schema:

```
grant select on schema::dbo to report_users;
```

Or the whole database:

```
grant select to report_users;
```

Comment: So basically in this case we have to create two seperate roles and add the users in the respective roles. Is giving permissions to users directly adivisable?

Comment: Granting permissions directly to users is not typically the best choice, as users come and go and multiple users often have the same needs.

Comment: I will assume, We can create multiple(n number of) roles based on the requirements and add users, and not grant permissions directly to users. Thanks a lot for your response David.